# Text not aligning in the middle vertically in the navigation meny

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, navbar

I was just wondering tpwhy the text in the navigation menu won't align vertically? Help Would be great thanks

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JWeFG/

.

.

.

```
<html>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include relevant code here: the "links to JSFiddle must include code" restriction is there for a reason.

Comment: Why exactly did you leave a bunch of whitespace in your question and include no useful code?...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just add a line height equal to the height of the containing element, I think this has bee discussed before. Though watch out for opera-mini, as I don't think there is support for line height on that browser.

look into table display as well.

```
.myFont1{
font-color: white;
font-family: arial;
font-face: arial;
line-height:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JWeFG/

Comment: Thank you I really needed help on that one

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `line-height: 50px;` in css class `myFont1`.

In general, `line-height` of text should be equal to height of container object, you are aligning with, in this case the container, `myMenuTop { height: 50px; }`.